# How to get lines separatly using a python curses textbox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I am rather new to curses and I'm curious if is possible getting every single line as a different string using a text box, or if there is a way to separate them. Below is the code that I'm using. As you can see there are just two lines, but I can't seem to find an easy way without manipulating the string somehow.

```
def boxinputstuff():
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Ctrl-G to send")

editwin = curses.newwin(2, 16, 2, 1)
rectangle(stdscr, 1, 0, 1 + 2 + 1, 1 + 16 + 1)
stdscr.refresh()

box = Textbox(editwin)

box.edit()

message = box.gather()
return message
```

I thought that it may be possible registering the "enter" key, used to start the next line of the box, but it seems a overly complicated and unorthodox solution.

Answer (score 0):

But manipulating the string *is* easy: `message.split('\n')`